# Which sort by value to give in order to indicate LAST in a unix timestamps array?

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash, unix-timestamp

I'm using lodash's [sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy) to sort an array of objects based on their timestamps (Unix time).
However, I want to set one of the objects to always be last (based on a certain condition).
If I wanted it to be first, I would give it a value of `0`.

```
let sortedArr = _.sortBy(arr, getSortByKey);

function getSortByKey(item) {
   if (item.key === 'lastKey') {
       return SORT_BY_KEY_LAST;
   }
   return item.timestamp;
}
```

What value should I return there to make `lastKey` always be last?
I'm trying to figure out what makes the most sense and is the most readable solution.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, I would use `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. Which is equal a ~53 bit integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all of the `timestamp` values are known to be in the past, I realized I can use [_.now()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#now) as a pretty elegant way to set a last sort by timestamp value.

Answer (score 0):

You could return a large value, for example

```
Number.MAX_VALUE
```